# Only include jar in gwt compile and not in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, maven, gwt, slf4j

I'm wanting to use the slf4j-gwt library https://github.com/FinamTrade/slf4j-gwt

But I only want to include it in my gwt compile, not in the war that is built as I'm having issues with tomcat startup calling GWT.create...

Is there a simple way to do this? I would expect the maven gwt compiler plugin to support this but I can't see that it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could exclude the artifact when building the WAR. Something like

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>
         WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-gwt-*.jar
      </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
</build>
```

should work.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

`<scope>provided</scope>` or `<optional>true</optional>`.

Neither one is semantically satisfying but that's what Maven gives us.

That being said, there are many reasons why you should rather split your project into several modules, with one module containing only client-side code and producing JavaScript and associated resources (through the GWT compiler) and one with only server-side dependencies; that way you never risk putting client-side classes or dependencies into your WAR.
See http://blog.ltgt.net/announcing-gwt-maven-archetypes-project/ for more about it, and sample projects (in the form of Maven archetypes).

Comment: Using provided is the most obviouls solution - surprised I didn't see it. thanks